# What does "Psychomodulatory" mean in the context of potentially psychoactive drugs?

Tags: pharmacology, terminology

What does "Psychomodulatory" mean in the context of potentially psychoactive drugs? That is, in this journal article http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0028390812001931 in the discussion (you will need special privileges to access the article via an institute or personal subscription or by paying for access) in the last sentence of the first paragraph it says

> However, euphol even when given in very high doses, (up to 100 mg/kg)
>   it did not show any evidence of psychomodulatory effects in the CNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, "psychomodulatory" would mean "eliciting a significant change (up *or* down) relative to baseline or compared to a control, placebo, or carrier," here specifically in CNS function.

This statement appears to refer to the results presented in section 3.8, *Effect of euphol in the cannabinoid tetrad tests*. Across a range of doses (3-100 mg/kg) and across four different assessments of CNS function: locomotor activity (rotarod), catalepsy (time to move off of a suspended ring), analgesia (tail flick in response to thermal stress), and body temperature (self explanatory). The results of these four are summarized in the figure below.

[image: Results of four tests of CNS function]

Basically the effects are not significantly different from each other between dosages or times. The lines sit more or less atop one another. Compare to this figure, where the differences are significant:

[image]